# RGSC Snapmatic: how to get photos with bigger resolutions?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v, rockstar-games-social-club

I can view and downloads my photos taken ingame from my Xbox 360 on [Rockstar Games Social Club - Snapmatic](http://fr.socialclub.rockstargames.com/games/gtav/snapmatic/myphotos), but I only get 640×360 pixels photos. Is there a way to get my photos with a bigger resolution?

I'm pretty sure that the images are reduced to this size in order to save bandwidth and space but I still ask this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately I don't think there is a way to get photos any bigger than this resolution, it is a limitation imposed by rockstar. The only alternative would be to use an xbox screen capture device, that would give you a slightly higher, 720p resolution image.